# How to know the signal delivered to thread

Tags: multithreading, linux-kernel, signals, multiprocessing

I have a ARM based embedded system running 2.6.33.
A main process-A creates another process-B. Both are aplication process with Real time RR policy. This proc-B creates few threads with pthread_create(). I guess one of the thread is doing some wrong and the process is killed.

On using wait() in process-A  i get status 1 returned (NORMAL) as shown below.

I want to know how to get which signal has been delivered to which thread inside 
process-B.

```
waitpid(-1, &status, WUNTRACED | WCONTINUED)
  and 
  if (WIFEXITED(status))
    printf("Process %d terminated normally, status %d\n", pid,WEXITSTATUS(status));
```

Followed the link but got the same status as 1.
http://www.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave/C/node32.html#SECTION003240000000000000000

Is there any other ways to find out the correct exit status of all threads and signal if any are sent to these threads ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, firstly, you should know that multithreading and signalling don't mix very well! This is in large reason due to the fact that signals are delivered to a PID; an MT app has 1 PID but multiple threads; which thread will 'get' / handle the signal?

Thus, the 'usual' strategy is to block all signal in all threads except one thread - a dedicated synchronous 'signal handler' thread (it typically issues the blocking sigwait(2); the return value is the signal that just arrived!).
[Here's a (simplistic) app](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/9301413/code_shared/tsig.c) to demo mixing threads and signalling.

Second, to understand some detail about how/why a process died - technically, received a signal - use sigaction(2) with the SA_SIGINFO flag. The signal handler signature now is:

```
void func(int signo, siginfo_t *info, void *context)
```

The struct siginfo_t will give you all the detail you need about how/why this process received this signal! Ref: [sigaction(2) man page](http://www.linuxmanpages.com/man2/sigaction.2.php).
Of course using this approach does mean that you use sigaction instead of sigwait.. async vs sync handling.
HTH.